# Is there any more information about the mines seen on the map of Chult in Tomb of Annihilation?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, maps, tomb-of-annihilation

In *Tomb of Annihilation*, in chapter 2, there is a map of Chult on p. 39, the "DM's version" with all of the hexes filled in and all of the locations named and displayed.

However, although many of the locations are named, there are various "mines" that are shown throughout the map (and we can tell that they are mines because the legend tells us that that's what that symbol means), but unlike the named locations, they are not expanded on later in chapter 2.

Below is a section of the map showing a few of these mines (shown by the symbol of a spade and pickaxe), as well as a few examples of named locations (in spoiler quotes in case any players currently in a ToA game shouldn't be looking at it):

> [image: Chult map]

What is the purpose of these mines being on the map? If my players find one, what am I supposed to do with that? **Is there any further information on these mines in the book?** Hopefully I'm just being blind and it's right there under my nose, but I can't seem to find anything else about these mines...

Comment: You aren't the only person with this question, related: https://www.reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/71jf20/mines_on_the_toa_map/ https://www.reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/7170wh/toa_question_about_mines_on_the_map/ https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/dungeons-dragons-discussion/dungeon-masters-only/8986-tomb-of-annhilation-mines some have taken to expanding on these locations: https://www.dmsguild.com/product/229320/Gem-Mines-of-Chult

Comment: @gszavae Thanks, at least I know that it's not a stupid question now. Interesting that others have even gone as far as to expand it themselves...

Answer (score 1):

All but one of the mines on the map are never specifically mentioned, the obvious exception being Wyrmheart Mine in the Kobold Mountains. The existance of the rest of the mines is mentioned several times indirectly in general area descriptions, but no specific characters, events, or maps are associated with them.

The mines are most likely included because the included Chult map is likely meant to be a general region map, and the other mines may be significant in a canceled or unreleased adventure.